# Remove and replace another onclick function in a div through pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this below span div and I copy this to another place in the DOM. But the `onclick` function I need to remove and place another `onclick` function.

```
<span class="plus childNode1" onclick="expand_collapseChildnodes('childNode1')" id="abc"></span>
```

Here I have to remove the `onclick="expand_collapseChildnodes('childNode1')"` for the copied element and replace it with `onclick="checkNodes('childNode1')"`.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear enough. What do you mean by 'remove and replace'? Can't you simply edit the markup?

Comment: The requirement is not clear. Provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a sample HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id ="d1">
        <span class="plus childNode1" onclick="expand_collapseChildnodes('childNode1')" id="abc"></span>
        </div>
        <div id ="d2">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now to move the element with id **abc** from DOM element with id **d1** to another with id **d2**

```
//get the element
var element = document.getElementById("abc");

//detach from source
document.getElementById("d1").removeChild(element);

//remove onclick attribute
element.removeAttribute("onclick");

//add the modified attribute
element.setAttribute("onclick", "sampleFunc()");

//attach the element to another source
document.getElementById("d2").appenChild(element);
```

Comment: @abhinna11 How do i get parameter of previous function then?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/KvnKZ/1/

```
var div=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var span=document.getElementById("abc");
var newSpan=span.cloneNode(true);
newSpan.setAttribute("id","newID"); //change id
newSpan.setAttribute("onclick","myFunc()"); //change onclick event handler

div[0].appendChild(newSpan);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("abc").onclick = function (){checkNodes('childNode1');}
```