# remove or override .onclick = function(){}

Tags: javascript

The site I am now the active developer on makes use of an externally loaded script. That contains a event listener on an given element in the DOM. The event is triggered with the following example

```
document.getElementById('my_id').onclick = function() { /*code*/ }
```

I have tried using the following examples to remove the listener to no avail.

```
document.getElementById('my_id').onclick = ''
document.getElementById('my_id').addEventListener('click', function(e){ /*code*/ })
document.getElementById('my_id').removeEventListener("click")
```

I have no control over this external code, but need to stop its behavior. My attempts fail currently I am trying to figure out why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove and replace another onclick function in a div through Pure Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331270/remove-and-replace-another-onclick-function-in-a-div-through-pure-javascript)

Comment: This assumes the onlick is a hardcoded attribute in the html itself, not the same, I already looked at that before posting.

Comment: @chris thoughts about the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign an empty function, like this:

```
document.querySelector('#main').onclick = () => {}
```

And working version

```js
document.querySelector('#main').onclick = () => console.log('clicked')
document.querySelector('#remove').onclick = () => document.querySelector('#main').onclick = () => {}
```

```html
<button id="main">Click me</button>
<button id="remove">Remove the listener</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `null` or empty function to `onclick`

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.onclick = function() {
  btn.onclick= null;
  alert("removed");
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

This question was already answered:

[How do you override inline onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629916/how-do-you-override-inline-onclick-event)

[Remove and replace another onclick function in a div through Pure Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331270/remove-and-replace-another-onclick-function-in-a-div-through-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('#main').onclick` did not work for me, because `onclick` event is not defined for basic `Element` class which is `querySelector` result. Instead, you need to cast to `HTMLButtonElement`:

```
(document.querySelector('abx-back-button') as HTMLButtonElement).onclick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
  this.router.navigate(['/segment-areas'], { state: { filterParams: this.filterQueryParams } });
};
```